# Create email verification url using Guardian

Tags: elixir, jwt, phoenix-framework, email-verification

I'm working on a site that implements user authentication (using Comeonin and Guardian).

I'm in the process of implementing email verification. I thought that I might take advantage of the functions in Guardian to generate the url using a JWT token. As per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36465189/json-web-token-jwt-as-a-url-for-email-activation), this seems like a plausible solution (as long as the url uses https and the token expires in a relatively short period of time).

Here's the code I've written so far:

```
def email_verification( user = %User{} ) do
  if ( user.email != nil ) do
    claims = Guardian.Claims.app_claims
       |> Map.put("email", user.email)
       |> Guardian.Claims.ttl({1, :hours})

    { :ok, jwt, full_claims } = Guardian.encode_and_sign(user, :email_verification, claims)

    Zoinks.Mailer.send_verification_email( user.email, jwt )
  end
end
```

I have put the email address in as a claim. The idea being that I could match the "email" claim with the email address in the database, once the user clicks the link.

However, I'm assuming that this is a bad idea - especially since the link will be exposed as clear text via email.

Following the pattern outlined in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102781/best-way-for-a-forgot-password-implementation#1102817), maybe I could generate a random number, hash it (using Comeonin), store it against the user and put that in as my claim instead? Is this a good idea, or am I completely off-track?

Assuming that I get this part of the solution working, is it okay to set the payload type to `:email_verification`?

Comment: What do you exactly mean with ```However, I'm assuming that this is a bad idea - especially since the link will be exposed as clear text via email.```? If you use a strong secret, there should be no issue using your approach AFAIK

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure - I'm inexperienced when it comes to security

Comment: I'm assuming that if you collect enough tokens (clear text via email), then it might be possible to apply a technique such as a Rainbow Table attack? If the security for the token in the email is compromised, then the website is as well - since it's using the same configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sending a JWT via e-mail is completely fine, as long a strong secret is used (but that's always important, despite the transport method)

**Quote from the comments:**

> I'm assuming that if you collect enough tokens (clear text via email), then it might be possible to apply a technique such as a Rainbow Table attack?

That's why you should pick a strong secret. The last part of the JWT, the signature, is a combination of `base64UrlEncode(header)`, `base64UrlEncode(payload)` and `secret` put into a strong hashing function like HMAC SHA256. For more security infos, there is a good description on [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/introduction/)

**Implementation**

You don't need to put the actual email inside the claims at all. A simple field like `email=true` should be enough, since your Serializer already puts the user id into the token. Just make sure a user can only be verified once and pick a strong secret!

Comment: If I allow the user to change their email address at any time (i.e. even before the user clicked the activation link) - wouldn't I need to confirm that the web token was for the email address in the database?

Comment: Yes, if you want to support validating different E-Mails for a single user, then storing the E-Mail inside the token is a correct approach! My thought was just about initial, single e-mail validation.